# Source model not found error message when exporting customer info

Tags: export, source-model

Hello good people of Stack Exchange.

Our small business has recently transferred our website to a new Magento hosting agency and we are experiencing an issue with the functionality for exporting customer information.

The process should be straight-forward:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/exporting-product-or-customer-information

However, when we select the entity type from the drop-down menu the page hangs on the 'Please wait...' message and the following error message appears:

Source model "donation/eav_attribute_source_giftaid" not found for attribute "giftaid"

We are a retail business so a giftaid message (which I assume relates to a charity setup) makes little sense to us.

We have flagged this issue with our agency but they haven't provided us with an answer and we need to get this functionality working.

If anyone with Magento experience could shed some light on the situation and offer any potential fixes it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The message would suggest that at some point your store had a donation module installed, but the code no longer exists. You have an attribute with the name `giftaid` and when Magento attempts to find the value to export it can't because the source class doesn't exist. I guess there are three ways to get around this issue:

1. Re-install the original module so that the source model exists (will be tricky if you don't know which module it was).
2. Attempt to create your own module that uses the same shortname and provide the class Magento is looking for.
3. If you're sure you don't need it, you could delete the attribute (`Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`, search for giftaid in the attribute code field, click into it and click delete).

**NB: I would highly recommend not attempting any of these steps in a live environment unless you really know what you're doing, especially Step 3 which you probably won't be able to recover from.**

Unless this is a feature of EE I don't think `donation` has ever been a core module, so if it doesn't seem required for your field it's rather curious that at exists in your system.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response Cags. I have taken a look at the Attribute Mangement area within Magento as you suggested and cannot find giftaid, although I have found donation (and is_donation). Is there any way to tell whether this is active or not? It is showing as: Required: No; System: No; Visible: Yes. Clicking into the attribute the settings are: Apply To: All Product Types; Visible on Product View Page...: Yes; Used in Product Listing: Yes. I think I will install Magento locally to get a better understanding of the system and pass on your findings to the agency. Thanks again!

Comment: There's not really a concept of an enabled/disabled attribute. Your products either have it or they don't. I'd be very curious to know why you have these attributes if you aren't a charity based company.

Comment: Thanks Cags. Yes, I'm very curious to know why we have these attributes as well seeing as we're a fashion retailer. Your advice has helped me explain all of this to the agency and I'll let you know once I have a response/fix.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, at some point, an extension or custom code was added to your Magento system.  This custom code, or extension, added a new product attribute type.  The production attribute's model name is `donation/eav_attribute_source_giftaid`.

Flash forward to today.  When you export your data, Magento is running through every product in the system.  From the sounds of things, it's encountered a product that has the above mentioned custom attribute.  However, when it tries to create the attribute programmatically for export it can't.

Unfortunately, without knowing the project history, it's impossible to debug this further.  It could be this extension has since been removed (or was an experiment by a previous programmer), but there's old inactive products hanging around.

It could be the site was moved improperly.

It could be some other error that's cropping up and interfering with things.

My guess if your "Magento hosting agency" isn't getting back to you because they provide hosting service, and not development service. At some point in its life your site crossed a threshold from being a standard Magento system into a system that's been heavily customized enough that they're not comfortable taking on that responsibility — not because they're mean or unethical, but because that's not the service they're selling.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Alan. I have indeed located the donation attribute in Magento. Is there any way to tell whether this is active or not? It is showing as: Required: No; System: No; Visible: Yes. Clicking into the attribute the settings are: Apply To: All Product Types; Visible on Product View Page...: Yes; Used in Product Listing: Yes. I think I will install Magento locally to get a better understanding of the system and pass on your findings to the agency. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3182742 There's not really such a thing as "active" or "inactive" when it comes to attributes.  If they're in the database, they're active.  I should have mentioned this above, but the problem is (most likely) that the corresponding PHP class/Magento model for the donation/eav_attribute_source_giftaid has been removed from your system

Comment: Thanks Alan, that's useful to know. I have passed all of this to the agency and will share the outcome. All the best.