# Export customers error "barkeloo payment"

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, customer, csv, export

I'm trying to export the customers, and shows me this error:

[image: barkeloo_payments_method]

How can I fix it? any idea?

Comment: What's your Magento version? As far as I know,  you created an attribute `bakerloo_payment_methods` and you declared a source model `bakerloopayment/source_paymentmethods` for this attribute. But this this source model wasn't declared. You can post more code lines about `bakerloo_payment_methods`.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Probably an extension did it, as soon as I removed Sweet Tooth extension my site got a lot of problems, it is a 1.9.7 magento version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source model not found error message when exporting customer info](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/source-model-not-found-error-message-when-exporting-customer-info)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you had en extension that added a product attribute and you either disabled it or uninstalled it but the attribute still remained in the database.
Run this query:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'bakerloo_payment_methods';
```

Then try the import again.